# Multi-level header GridView WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, wpfdatagrid

I need to set the listview view to a gridview that have a complex header like this (based on a 3 dimensional object list i created):

```
| ---------- LEVEL 0 ------------  |
| -- Level 1a --  | -- Level 1b -- |  
| Lvl A |  Lvl B  | Lvl A  | Lvl B |
```

EDIT: This is more ore less my object model

```
public class Measures
{
    public string Caption { get; set; }
    public List<Threshold> ThresholdList { get; set; }
}

public class Threshold
{
    public string Caption { get; set; }

    public double Value1 { get; set; }
    public double Value2 { get; set; }
    public double Value3 { get; set; }
    public double Value4 { get; set; }
}
```

i've to bind a dynamic list of `Measures` (this is my level 0), then a dynamic list of `Threshold` (level 1a...)  and for each threshold display values1 to 4 if they are != 0

Comment: What about stacking multiple gridviewrowheaderpresenter? It could be a good way? I'm stuck in this problem...

Comment: Can we get a better idea of what your object model / data looks like?

Comment: @RQDQ i've added the objectmodel i need to display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
<ListBox x:Name="MainListBox">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Label Content="{Binding Path=Caption}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />

                        <ListBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ThresholdList}" >
                            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                        <Label Content="{Binding Path=Caption}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />

                                        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <Label Content="{Binding Path=Value1}" />
                                            <Label Content="{Binding Path=Value2}" />
                                            <Label Content="{Binding Path=Value3}" />
                                            <Label Content="{Binding Path=Value4}" />
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>


                        </ListBox>

                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

You might need to convert the Value1, Value2 properties into a collection in order to dynamically display the non-zero ones and use the same ListBox/StackPanel approach that I used to display the thresholds.

This gives the output:

[image: Screenshot]

And just to complete the post, here is the code I used:

```
List<Measures> measuresList = new List<Measures>();

Measures measures = new Measures()
{
    Caption = "LEVEL 0",
    ThresholdList = new List<Threshold>()
};

measures.ThresholdList.Add(new Threshold()
{
    Caption = "Level 1a",
    Value1 = 1,
    Value2 = 2,
    Value3 = 3,
    Value4 = 4
});

measures.ThresholdList.Add(new Threshold()
{
    Caption = "Level 1b",
    Value1 = 5,
    Value2 = 6,
    Value3 = 7,
    Value4 = 8
});

measuresList.Add(measures);

this.MainListBox.ItemsSource = measuresList;
```

Comment: Thank you, seems to be a good hint, i'll try asap! My only doubt is that i need to use a list view cause the objectmodel i wrote so far is repeated for a n row (representing n member). Now i'm using simpler solution (cause project's deadlines don't wait), but i'm still searching a more elegant solution!

Comment: @michele - this approach still works for multiple measure objects and multiple Threshold objects.  Is that what you're trying to solve?

Comment: I try your code example. It works, but i need to set that tree structure on the header of a listview, rows in listview have to display only the bottom level values. Your example set the tree inside every row and i'm trying to avoid it. I'm thinking that the only solution is to write a full custom control. Thank you again

Comment: @michele - you're not explaining what you need very well.  I gave you a sample that looks very much like what you pointed out in your question.  I also pointed out that it will work for multiple Measures, ThresholdList objects.  Perhaps the data objects you provided aren't what you're trying to display?

Comment: My original question was about getting a listview with a multi-level header. The objectmodel i provided was about the structure i have to bind to the header. The same object model is included in n other objects that i've to display in the listview items. I'm sorry if i wasn't so clear, maybe i need to brainstorm a bit more to clear my doubt about the datastructure. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Level 0 Is a ListView? Level 1A and level 1b are Gridviews that you want inside two different templated columns inside the level 0 List view? Then level A and level b are two more grid views inside 2 more templated columns in level 1a and level 1b?

You might be able to convert the same concept this nested GridView uses into WPF

http://forums.asp.net/t/1071521.aspx

I haven't tried it myself in wpf, but gridviews appeared to be built similarly.
Just use panels instead of Divs, and less head aches with having to wory about client/serverside calls.

Also Datasets work nicer then lists.

Here is some psuedo code on how I've set up Nested Datasets before

```
DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
        ds1.Tables.Add(m_DataLayer.GetRealA_Data(X, Y).Copy()); Returns Table ["A"]
        ds1.Tables.Add(m_DataLayer.GetB_Empty().Copy());// Returns Table ["B"]
        ds1.Tables.Add(m_DataLayer.GetC_Empty().Copy());// Returns Table ["C"]
        ds1.Tables.Add(m_DataLayer.GetD_Empty().Copy());// Returns Table ["D"]

        ds1.Relations.Add("b", ds1.Tables["A"].Columns["A_id"], ds1.Tables["B"].Columns["A_id"]);
        ds1.Relations.Add("c", ds1.Tables["B"].Columns["B_id"]
            , ds1.Tables["C"].Columns["B_id"]);
        ds1.Relations.Add("d", ds1.Tables["C"].Columns["C_id"]
            , ds1.Tables["D"].Columns["D_id"]);

        dt_TheGridViewDataSet = ds1;
        TheGridView.DataSource = ds1;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the hint. Unfortunately, working with nested gridviews not seems to be the solution for my problem. I need to have only one listview, that displays the lowest level (lvl A, lvlB): upper levels are only descriptive, i need them to know to which object refers lvlA ect.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about how it should behave - your header that is?

It is easy enough to make a header that looks like the one you suggest - you could build it with some grids programatically - but that is just the header. Should you also be able to resize it like you normally can with a listview header?

Maybe you looking for something like a TreeListView?

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TreeListView.aspx

I think that is what I would go after to display multidimentional data - it is easy to understand and use, where a custom listview can be hard to implement to behave right.

Comment: thank you for the hint. When I've some free time i wanna try that control!